# Remove top shadow from SelectOneMenu

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to get rid of this little inside shadow in a SelectOneMenu

[image]

```
<h:outputLabel styleClass='defaultOutputLabel' for="sexe" value="Sexe: *" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="sexe" styleClass='selectMenu' required="true" requiredMessage="Vous devez sélectionner un sexe.">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel='Homme' itemValue='Homme' />
     <f:selectItem itemLabel='Femme' itemValue='Femme' />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

I tried:

```
box-shadow: none !important;
border-style: none !important;
```

I can't see what other selector it could be. Any ideas ?

**UPDATE :**
Thanks to tt_dev for the solution:
`box-shadow` property on the `.ui-inputfield` part.

Comment: What you're looking for is something like -webkit-appearance: none; or border: 0 on the select. If you show the code it would be a little easier to specifically help :).

Comment: it's the `box-shadow` attribute applied to `ui-inputfield` css class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried both of your propositions and it doesn't work. The border: 0 removes the outter border but that little shadow border stays.

Comment: Here is the code:

                            <h:outputLabel styleClass='defaultOutputLabel' for="sexe" value="Sexe: *" />
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="sexe" styleClass='selectMenu' required="true" requiredMessage="Vous devez sélectionner un sexe.">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel='Homme' itemValue='Homme' />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel='Femme' itemValue='Femme' />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>

Comment: Thank you tt_dev it worked.

.selectMenu .ui-inputfield {
box-shadow: none !important;
}

Comment: Put the code in a fiddle or in your question please, not in the comments.

Comment: Ok sorry ajmajmajma I will remember for next time. I'm not very used to stackoverflow :) I don't even know how to flag a comment as a valid answer lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's the `box-shadow` attribute applied to `ui-inputfield` css class.

you can use the following css code as you mentioned:

```
.ui-inputfield { box-shadow: none !important; }
```

Comment: Please try sacrificing `!important;`, if possible. I always read `!important;` as *not important*. Thank you.

Comment: unfortunately, if we don't use `!important` in this case, the component will go back to its original style after primefaces ajax `update`. any other alternatives that i don't know?

Comment: Read about css specificity, e.g. on mozdev.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity Everyone should read that. Lots of info on how to circumvent !important